# ASP.NET MVC with jQuery Validation - messages customization and localization

Tags: asp.net-mvc, localization, jquery-validate, data-annotations

I have ASP.NET MVC (4) project which localization is supported by the framework. Should I change browser settings to another language, framework automatically picks up the right resource file.

However, because I am using knockoutjs I fall back to jQuery validation at those views. Unfortunately there's no automatic support for localization there.

My question is - what are the best practices and ways to customize and localize jQuery validation messages so they will be picked automatically together with all MVC resources?

*Something that jQuery validation messages will behave in a similar manner to Data Annotations messages given resources and message Ids.*

In particular -

1. How to I make jQuery pick up the message *I want* from the resources instead of its default "This field is required", so it will print something like "Please enter email" and
2. How can I make jQuery print the same customized message *in another language automatically* should I change browser language ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 1)  How to I make jQuery pick up the message I want from the resources instead of its default "This field is required", so it will print something like "Please enter email".

The following is called to over-ride messages at any time.  The strings below can be replaced with variables.

```
jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.messages, {
    required: "This field is required.",
    remote: "Please fix this field.",
    email: "Please enter a valid email address.",
    url: "Please enter a valid URL.",
    date: "Please enter a valid date.",
    dateISO: "Please enter a valid date (ISO).",
    number: "Please enter a valid number.",
    digits: "Please enter only digits.",
    creditcard: "Please enter a valid credit card number.",
    equalTo: "Please enter the same value again.",
    accept: "Please enter a value with a valid extension.",
    maxlength: jQuery.validator.format("Please enter no more than {0} characters."),
    minlength: jQuery.validator.format("Please enter at least {0} characters."),
    rangelength: jQuery.validator.format("Please enter a value between {0} and {1} characters long."),
    range: jQuery.validator.format("Please enter a value between {0} and {1}."),
    max: jQuery.validator.format("Please enter a value less than or equal to {0}."),
    min: jQuery.validator.format("Please enter a value greater than or equal to {0}.")
});
```

Otherwise, you can get more specific when declaring your rules within `.validate()`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myform').validate({ // initialize the plugin
        rules: {
            field1: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 5
            }
        },
        messages: {
            field1: {
                required: "custom message for field 1 required",
                minlength: "custom message: {0} chars required"
            }
        }
    });

});
```

**DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/XV3ZR/**

To *dynamically* change any messages *after* the plugin is first initialized, requires an over-ride by using [the `rules('add')` method](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules#.22add.22rules).

```
$('#field1').rules('add', {
    messages: {
        required: "field 1 required",
        minlength: "{0} chars required"
    }
});
```

**DEMO 2: http://jsfiddle.net/PJGgE/1/**

> 2)  How can I make jQuery print the same customized message in another language automatically should I change browser language ?

I'm not sure what you mean by "change browser language", but again, the methods in #1 above are the only ways, AFAIK.  These are just strings and you'll have to translate them manually or via outside methods.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can give on the server to the client script file with localization depending client's browser settings (something like i18n)